# Installing app in Android emulator shows "This app is not available for your device"

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm trying to install a Google Play app on an Android emulator on a Windows 10 machine, but see the message "This app is not available for your device". I've tried creating different virtual devices (Pixel 3 w/Play Store, Pixel 4 w/Play Store, Nexus 5 w/Play Store, etc.) with different SDK versions (Android 9.0, 10.0, and 11.0) using both Android Studio and Visual Studio, but all result in the same message.

I've tried the "Clear Cache" and "Clear Storage" tricks on the virtual device's Google Play app, but that didn't work for me.

If I load Google Play Store in a Chrome browser and find the app, I get the same message, but I also see that my device that is incompatible is named "Google sdk_gphone_x86".  I've also pulled up the same app in an Incognito browser window and it looks like it will install, but once I sign in to my Google account, I get the same message.

Other coworkers are able to install the app with a similar configuration so I know this app can be installed.  It looks like it may be connected to my Google account.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what else to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several days of troubleshooting, I finally found the answer so I thought I'd post here for anyone else occasionally experiencing this problem.

For some reason, this particular app didn't work with Hyper-V hardware acceleration.  In order to finally get it working, I disabled Hyper-V and installed HAXM instead.

Comment: Where do I have to disable Hyper-V and install HAXM instead of it?